# Spring WS has trouble with namespace declaration for schema instance

Tags: java, spring, soap, soapui, spring-ws

This is my request `Envelope`, with the `xsi:xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` declaration put in my `myRequestMethod` XML tag:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:sd="http://www.foo.bar/ws" 
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body >
     <sd:myRequestMethod xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <sd:name xsi:nil="true"/>
```

This works (tested with SoapUI), but when my user generates soap client, the `xsi:xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` declaration is automatically put in the `Envelope` tag like this (the most outer tag):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:sd="http://www.foo.bar/ws" 
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body >
     <sd:myRequestMethod>
       <sd:name xsi:nil="true"/>
```

This gives him

```
The namespace associated with the prefix 'xsi' could not be resolved.
```

Is this normal behaviour, that soap can't understand it if its not in inner tag? Or I can configure my spring-ws somehow to allow it? **The user auto generates the client and request, so he can't change his side.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the related bug from castor JIRA.

I think it is not resolved yet. So this remains a bug.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/CASTOR-2813

> To be more specific, the problem arises when namespace information is provided, for example, at the root element of an XML document, and someone wants to unmarshall a sub-node of that document (calling Unmarshaller#unmarshal(org.w3c.dom.Node)). The sub-node won't have any XML-namespace attributes that Castor is looking for as the namespaces were declared at the root element.
>
> In this case, an attribute (xsi.*) is met at some element while Castor
>   doesn't know the namespace. So it probably thinks that the XML is
>   invalid and throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

Both XMLs are instances of legitimate use of XML Namespaces. I suspect a bug in the document processing infrastructure where the contents of *body* are processed without proper propagation of all declared namespace prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

While creating the WebService methods, you can specify the nameSpace. If you make that to generate on its own, it gave me the similar error. After changing the namespace, it is resolved.

Try to do something like this,

`@WebMethod(operationName = "operation")`

`@WebResult(name = "Response",targetNamespace = ServiceConstant.TARGET_NAME_SPACE)`

`Response operation(@WebParam(name = "input", mode = WebParam.Mode.IN)Request Request);`

So this time you have defined customized namespace, which will be followed by client whether SOAPUI/ SOA Client...

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't have those, my methods are defined by XSD and endpoints are in Java. Can you be more precise, please? My endpoint has something similar : `@PayloadRoot(localPart = "myRequestMethod", namespace = "http://www.foo.bar/ws")`.

Comment: While we define the WebService using apache CXF for SOAP, the above mentioned way suits defining the methods with nameSpace.